# Java: can't close Client connection without closing Server

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

I made a previous post a bit back working on getting a two-way server/client socket connection working. I've largely succeeded yet, but I still have one more step as a barrier. I'd like to make it so the client disconnects after they perform an operation, but the server remains up and can take in another client operation until the client makes a specific response. I'm attempting to do this through while loops in both the client and server. This is my server class:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class ServerDemo {
    private Socket mySocket = null;
    private ServerSocket server = null;
    private static ObjectInputStream in=null;
    private static ObjectOutputStream out=null;
    private static Payload myPayload=new Payload();

    public ServerDemo(int port) throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        double time=0;
        int bytes=0;
        try
        {
               server = new ServerSocket(port);
               System.out.println("Server started");
               System.out.println("Waiting for a client ...");
        }
        catch(IOException i)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
            myPayload.setRepeat(false);
        }
        try {
               while(myPayload.getRepeat()==true) {
               mySocket = server.accept();
               System.out.println("Client accepted");
               in = new ObjectInputStream(
                       new BufferedInputStream(mySocket.getInputStream()));
               out = new ObjectOutputStream(mySocket.getOutputStream());
               myPayload.setDataPasses(10);
               while (myPayload.getCurr()<myPayload.getDataPasses())
               {
                    try
                    {
                         myPayload= (Payload) in.readObject();
                         myPayload.raisePasses();
                         out.writeObject(myPayload);
                        
                    }
                    catch(IOException i)
                    {
                        System.out.println(i);
                        myPayload.setRepeat(false);
                    }
               }
               System.out.println("Closing connection");
               mySocket.close();
               in.close();
               System.out.println("Operation Complete");
               System.out.println("Client Address: "+myPayload.getClient());
               System.out.println("Server Address: "+myPayload.getServer());
               time=System.nanoTime()-(myPayload.getTime());
               time=time/1000000000;
               System.out.println("Total Time (in seconds): "+time);
               bytes=(int) ( ((myPayload.getPacket().length)*myPayload.getDataPasses())/time);
               System.out.println("Bytes per Second: "+bytes);
         }
        }
        catch(IOException i)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
            myPayload.setRepeat(false);
        }
    }
 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ServerDemo server=new ServerDemo(5000);
    }

}
```

This is my client class:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class ClientDemo {
    private Socket mySocket = null;
    private ObjectInputStream in= null;
    private ObjectOutputStream out = null;
    private static long roundTrips=1;
    private static Payload myPayload=new Payload();
    
    public ClientDemo(String address, int port) throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        int packageSize=1;
        double time=0;
        int bytes=0; 
 try 
        {
            mySocket = new Socket(address, port);
            System.out.println("Connected"); 
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(mySocket.getOutputStream());
            in = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(mySocket.getInputStream()));
           
        }
        catch(UnknownHostException u)
        {
            System.out.println(u);
        }
        catch(IOException i)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
            while (myPayload.getCurr()<myPayload.getDataPasses())
            {
                
                try
                {
                        if(myPayload.getCurr()==0) {
                        myPayload.setTime(System.nanoTime());
                    }
                    out.writeObject(myPayload);
                    myPayload= (Payload) in.readObject();
                }
                catch(IOException i)
                {
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
            }
        try
        {
            in.close();
            out.close();
            mySocket.close();
            System.out.println("Operation Complete");
            System.out.println("Client Address: "+myPayload.getClient());
            System.out.println("Server Address: "+myPayload.getServer());
            time=System.nanoTime()-(myPayload.getTime());
            time=time/1000000000;
            System.out.println("Total Time (in seconds): "+time);
            bytes=(int) ( ((myPayload.getPacket().length)*myPayload.getDataPasses())/time);
            System.out.println("Bytes per Second: "+bytes);
            System.out.println("");
        }
        catch(IOException i)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean isValid=false;
        String response="";
        int size=16384;
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        ClientDemo client=null;
        String server="";
        while (size>-1) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a max data packet size. Enter -1 to end the program");
            while(isValid==false) {
                response=myScanner.next();
                if(Long.parseLong(response)>=-1 && Long.parseLong(response)<=16384) {
                    isValid=true;
                    size=Integer.parseInt(response);
                    if(size>-1) {
                        myPayload.setPacket(fillPacket(size));
                    }
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid Response. Please enter a value between 1 and 16384.");
                }
            }
        if(size==-1) {
            System.out.println("Closing server...");
            myPayload.setRepeat(false);
            client= new ClientDemo(server, 5000);

        }
        else {
            isValid=false;
            System.out.println("Please enter an amount of data passes.");
            while(isValid==false) {
                response=myScanner.next();
                if(Long.parseLong(response)>=1) {
                    isValid=true;
                    roundTrips=Long.parseLong(response);
                    myPayload.setDataPasses(roundTrips);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid Response. Please enter a value of 1 or greater.");
                }
            }
            isValid=false;
            System.out.println("Please enter your client address.");
            response=myScanner.next();
            myPayload.setClient(response);
            System.out.println("Please enter a server to connect to.");
            response=myScanner.next();
            server=response;
            myPayload.setServer(server);
            myPayload.reset();
            client= new ClientDemo(server, 5000);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static int[] fillPacket(int size) {
        int[] thePacket= new int[size];
        int current=0;
        while(current<size) {
            for(int counter=0;counter<100;counter++) {
                if(current<size) {
                    thePacket[current]=counter;
                    current++;
                }
            }
        }
        return thePacket;
    }
}
```

When I attempt to run both, the operation I have set up works completely fine, and entering -1 to close the program works but I run into errors when performing operations beyond that. Attempting to set size to -1 to end the program at this point causes an endless loop of

```
java.io.EOFException
```

inside ServerDemo, while entering what should be a valid packet size between 0 and 16384 instead produces an endless stream of

```
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
```

inside ClientDemo. Perhaps most strangely, the latter error only SOMETIMES occurs, not always. If anyone has any pointers on how to get this correctly working and remedying these errors, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: This is basic network programming.  Your main thread should do nothing but wait for connections.  Each time a connection is received, you must spawn a new thread to handle it.  This leaves the server in a state to receive the next connection.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather change approach. The usual one when doing this kind of stuff is create a thread to listen on your port, then, when a client connects, immediately dispatch the new task to a thread pool and continue listening.

This way not only your server will continue listening after the client disconnects, but also will be able to serve multiple clients in parallel (up to the thread pool size).

Also please use try-with-resources whenever possible to easily avoid resource leaking.

So your code could be changed to something like this:

**Server class**

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class ServerDemo {
    private int port;
    private Thread listenThread;
    private ExecutorService serverPool;

    public ServerDemo(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public synchronized void startServer() {
        serverPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);       

        listenThread = new Thread(() -> {
            try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port)) {
                System.out.println(String.format("Listening on port %d", port));
                System.out.println("1");
                while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                    System.out.println("2");
                    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                    System.out.println("3");
                    if(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
                        serverPool.submit(new ClientTask(clientSocket));
                    System.out.println("4");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Error processing client connection");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            System.out.println("ListenThread stopped");
        }, "ListenThread");

        listenThread.start();
    }
    
    public synchronized void stopServer() {
        System.out.println("Stopping server...");
        if (serverPool != null) {
            serverPool.shutdown();
            serverPool = null;
        }
        
        if(listenThread != null) {
            listenThread.interrupt();

            try (Socket voidSocket = new Socket("localhost", port)) {
                // Void socket to unlock the accept() call              
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            
            listenThread = null;
        }
    }

    private class ClientTask implements Runnable {
        private final Socket clientSocket;

        private ClientTask(Socket clientSocket) {
            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Client accepted");
            Payload myPayload = new Payload();
            try (ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream())) {

                myPayload.setDataPasses(10);
                while (myPayload.getCurr() < myPayload.getDataPasses()) {
                    try {
                        myPayload = (Payload) in.readObject();
                        myPayload.raisePasses();
                        out.writeObject(myPayload);
    
                    } catch (IOException i) {
                        System.out.println(i);
                        break;
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        System.err.println("Error finding class to deserialize");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Operation Complete");
                System.out.println("Client Address: " + myPayload.getClient());
                System.out.println("Server Address: " + myPayload.getServer());
                double time = System.nanoTime() - (myPayload.getTime());
                time = time / 1000000000;
                System.out.println("Total Time (in seconds): " + time);
                int bytes = (int) (((myPayload.getPacket().length) * myPayload.getDataPasses()) / time);
                System.out.println("Bytes per Second: " + bytes);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                System.err.println("Error opening client I/O streams");
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                System.out.println("Closing connection");
                clientSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Error closing client connection");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            if(!myPayload.getRepeat())
                stopServer();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        ServerDemo server = new ServerDemo(5000);
        server.startServer();
        
        // do other stuff including trapping for sigterm, then call server.stopServer() if needed
    }

}
```

**Client class**

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ClientDemo {

    private static void executeClientJob(Payload myPayload, int port) {
        double time = 0;
        int bytes = 0;
        try (Socket mySocket = new Socket(myPayload.getServer(), port);
                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(mySocket.getOutputStream());
                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(mySocket.getInputStream()))) {

            System.out.println("Connected");
            while (myPayload.getCurr() < myPayload.getDataPasses()) {

                if (myPayload.getCurr() == 0)
                    myPayload.setTime(System.nanoTime());

                out.writeObject(myPayload);
                myPayload = (Payload) in.readObject();
            }

            System.out.println("Operation Complete");
            System.out.println("Client Address: " + myPayload.getClient());
            System.out.println("Server Address: " + myPayload.getServer());
            time = System.nanoTime() - (myPayload.getTime());
            time = time / 1000000000;
            System.out.println("Total Time (in seconds): " + time);
            bytes = (int) (((myPayload.getPacket().length) * myPayload.getDataPasses()) / time);
            System.out.println("Bytes per Second: " + bytes);
            System.out.println("");
        } catch (UnknownHostException u) {
            u.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
            c.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void testAutomatic() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            Payload myPayload = new Payload();
            myPayload.setPacket(fillPacket(40));
            executeClientJob(myPayload, 5000);
        }
        Payload stopPayload = new Payload();
        stopPayload.setRepeat(false);
        executeClientJob(stopPayload, 5000);
    }

    private static void testInteractive() {
        Payload myPayload;
        boolean repeat;
        do {
            myPayload = readPayloadSettings();
            repeat = myPayload.getRepeat(); 
            executeClientJob(myPayload, 5000);
        } while (repeat);
    }

    private static Payload readPayloadSettings() {
        Payload ret = new Payload();
        int size = 60;

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a max data packet size. Enter -1 to end the program");
        while (true) {
            String response = myScanner.next();
            if (Long.parseLong(response) >= -1 && Long.parseLong(response) <= 16384) {
                size = Integer.parseInt(response);
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid Response. Please enter a value between 1 and 16384.");
            }
        }
        if (size == -1) {
            System.out.println("Closing server...");
            ret.setRepeat(false);
        } else {
            ret.setPacket(fillPacket(size));
            System.out.println("Please enter an amount of data passes.");
            while (true) {
                String response = myScanner.next();
                if (Long.parseLong(response) >= 1) {
                    ret.setDataPasses(Long.parseLong(response));
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid Response. Please enter a value of 1 or greater.");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Please enter your client address.");
            ret.setClient(myScanner.next());
            System.out.println("Please enter a server to connect to.");
            ret.setServer(myScanner.next());
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public static int[] fillPacket(int size) {
        int[] thePacket = new int[size];
        int current = 0;
        while (current < size) {
            for (int counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++) {
                if (current < size) {
                    thePacket[current] = counter;
                    current++;
                }
            }
        }
        return thePacket;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        testInteractive();
        //testAutomatic();
    }
}
```

**Payload class** (with defaults to quick create an automatic test)

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Payload implements Serializable {

    private int curr=0;
    private long dataPasses=5;
    private long time;
    private String client="localhost";
    private String server="localhost";
    private int[] packet=new int[0];
    private boolean repeat=true;

    public Payload() {
    }
    
    public int getCurr() {
        return curr;
    }

    public void setCurr(int curr) {
        this.curr = curr;
    }

    public long getDataPasses() {
        return dataPasses;
    }
    public void setDataPasses(long roundTrips) {
        this.dataPasses = roundTrips;
    }

    public long getTime() {
        return time;
    }
    
    public void setTime(long nanoTime) {
        time = nanoTime;
        
    }

    public String getClient() {
        return client;
    }
    
    public void setClient(String client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public String getServer() {
        return server;
    }
    
    public void setServer(String server) {
        this.server = server;
    }

    public int[] getPacket() {
        return packet;
    }
    
    public void setPacket(int[] packet) {
        this.packet = packet;
    }

    public boolean getRepeat() {
        return repeat;
    }
    
    public void setRepeat(boolean r) {
        this.repeat = r;
    }

    public void reset() {
        curr=0;
        dataPasses=0;
    }

    public void raisePasses() {
        curr++;     
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you. All I need to know now is this: how do I manually close the server thread? I'd still like to be able to read in an input from a client that closes not just the client, but the server as well, and would appreciate any advice there.

Comment: Just call the `stopServer()` method wherever you need to shutdown the pool and stop listening. Of course you should have visibility on the original `server` object

Comment: Hmm, I was messing around with the code some more, and it seems like I still get the endless stream of Java.SocketException when attempting to perform multiple operations. I just hadn't seen it because I simply attempted to cancel on my second attempt, which is my bad. If you have any idea why this thread still doesn't work, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I updated the above solution with full code for client server and payload. 
Please check out the `testInteractive()` and `testAutomatic()` methods in `ClientDemo`